# Forgot my Laptop BIOS Password

Tags: laptop, password-recovery, reset, cmos

I forgot my old laptop BiOS Password, i am trying to reset it. I have already removed the hard disk and attached it with the other laptop, so its not about the data, I have already extracted all my data. I cannot install new operating system, so no solution from within windows is possible. I have already tried the following things

1. Removed the CMOS battery for 3 days.
2. I have two jumpers near RAM slots J5 and J6, i have tried to short them with metal, no success (may be i am donig something wrong here)
3. Tried couple of backdoor passwords from different web pages, nothing worked.

Please check the attached screenshots.

**Laptop Model Acer Aspire V5 Series Model ZRQ**

[Mother Board Jumpers image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1LEl.jpg)

Comment: Most modern laptops are designed to prevent the firmware password from being reset.  There is a good chance you will be required to send the device to Acer in order to accomplish your goal

Answer (score 1):

Most laptops from (say) a half dozen years or newer do not have resettable passwords. You do need a record of your password. Otherwise the laptop will not work.

You can try contacting the manufacturer to see if they can help. Manufacturers vary in the support they can provide.

Comment: cost is too high almost equal to the price of new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Short G2201 jumper on motherboard under one of the RAM slots, I assume with the CMOS battery inserted.

Edit: Keep shorted until after BIOS post, switch off, remove short and reinstall DIMM modules. Switch back on and test.

Comment: Why do you suggest G2201?

Comment: Service manual procedure.

Comment: Please post the service manual @TheLensta

Comment: there is no G2201 Jumper behind the RAM SLOT